# How to create a form to my users in wordpress for adding new posts in front-end?

Tags: wordpress, post, wordpress-theming

What I'm trying to do is have front-end add new post page for my users only, and also i need it in custom post types.

Answer (score 0):

[GravityForms](http://www.gravityforms.com) offers this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple and fairly easy-to-use plugin called "User Submitted Posts" which might provide the functionality you are looking for.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-submitted-posts/